# Rails 5 query for a condition in a third table using joins?

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

this are my models - first:

```
 class Negocio < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :cuenta_clientes
end
```

second

```
class CuentaCliente < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :negocio
  has_many :pago_clientes
 end
```

and third:

```
class PagoCliente < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :cuenta_cliente
end
```

I want to select all the PagoCliente that a Negocio has. But there is no references between Negocio and PagoCliente (and i cannot modify tables and relations) so this is my attempt:

```
 pagos = PagoCliente.joins(cuenta_cliente: :negocio).where(negocio: {id: params[:negocio_id}])
```

but this is my error output:

```
ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: PG::UndefinedTable: ERROR:  missing FROM-clause entry for table "negocio"
LINE 1: ...cios"."id" = "cuenta_clientes"."negocio_id" WHERE "negocio"....
```

so, Which is the correct syntax for this query? thanks. I'm using Postgres...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The table is plural, try:

```
pagos = PagoCliente.joins(cuenta_cliente: :negocio).where(negocios: {id: params[:negocio_id}])
```

Answer (score 0):

if you are getting `params[:negocio_id]` you can do  this way

1-

```
cuenta_cliente_ids= Negocio.find(params[:negocio_id]).cuenta_clientes.pluck(:id)
```

2-

```
pago_clientes = PagoCliente.where("cuenta_cliente_id IN (?)", cuenta_cliente_ids)
```

however with your query i think there is typo here i modify it

```
 pagos = PagoCliente.joins(cuenta_cliente: :negocio).where(negocios: {id: params[:negocio_id]})
```

ps correct me if i'm wrong